# An issue occurs when i attempt to run batch this file. is it a syntax error?

Tags: windows, batch-file

i dont see why it isnt working.
if you could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.
i run the file and it just exits out, as if the code is missing.

```batch
cls
echo //========================================//
echo \\   ---     ---  ---------- ----------   \\
echo //  |    \  |  |  |        | |        |   //
echo \\  |  \  \ |  |   --    --   --    --    \\
echo //  |  |\  \|  |     |  |       |  |      //
echo \\  |  | \     |     |  |       |  |      \\
echo //  |__|  \____|     |__|       |__|      //
echo \\========================================\\
echo           press any key to begin
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the pipes `|` with a carret (`^|`).
However you should store ascii art in a txt file and use `type my_banner.txt` in order to display it. This is easier ...

Comment: It would help if you told the user how to escape special characters.

Comment: Easier, sure. But if you want to distribute the script, you need to include the text file.